# cant import files in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import an excel file into phpmyadmin but getting this error. can someone help?

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> nea

Comment: Did you visit here : http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064

Comment: If your inserting into an existing table, make sure that the number of columns in your excel sheet matches the number fields in your table.  There are quite a few things that could go wrong to bring this error, but the number of fields is a more common one. Is this actually xls that you are importing or did you convert to csv?